# use Lilypond to transpose pattern around circle of fifths

Tags: lilypond, typesetting, music-notation

I want to provide a pattern (e.g., the C major arpeggio, C E G) and have Lilypond automatically show it transposed (as one score) in all 12 scales.

Here's my current attempt:

```
music = { c' e' g' s }

\new Staff {
  \transpose c c   { \music }
  \transpose c f   { \music }
  \transpose c bes { \music }
  \transpose c ees { \music }
  \transpose c aes { \music }
  \transpose c des { \music }
  \transpose c fis { \music }
  \transpose c b   { \music }
  \transpose c e   { \music }
  \transpose c a   { \music }
  \transpose c d   { \music }
  \transpose c g   { \music }
}
```

I don't know how to add a text above each pattern indicating the transposition key (e.g., C, F, Bb, etc...).  I would like the final product to look something like this:

[image]

Note: I would like this code to work regardless of the length of the pattern (which could be longer than one measure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want automatic note names, it can be achieved by transposing chords. Something like this produces a similar result to what you show. It is not simple and elegant but it is automatic in the sense that you don't need to know the destination chord previously.

```
\version "2.19.31"

cOne=\chordmode {c1} 

mOne={ c'4 e' g' s }


<<
  \new ChordNames{
    \transpose c f {\transpose c f { \cOne }}
    \transpose c f { \cOne }
    \cOne  
    \transpose c g { \cOne }
    \transpose c g { \transpose c g { \cOne }}
    \transpose c g { \transpose c g { \transpose c g { \cOne }}}
  }

  \new Staff {
    \transpose c f,  {\transpose c f { \mOne }}
    \transpose c f { \mOne }
    \mOne
    \transpose c g { \mOne }
    \transpose c g, { \transpose c g { \mOne }}
    \transpose c g, { \transpose c g { \transpose c g { \mOne }}}
  }
>>
```

[image: sample lilypond output]

Comment: Thank you, @Paco, this is very nice.  The only remaining issue is to make it work with patterns that are longer than one measure.  Currently, if one sets `cOne = \chordmode {c1}` for a two measure pattern (e.g., `mOne = { c'4 e' g' g' e' c' s s }`), the chord names move faster than the pattern.  I would like to have chord names and patterns automatically aligned, regardless of the length of the pattern (i.e., I do not want to have to type `cOne = \chordmode {c1 s}` for a two measure pattern).